# How to do Windows Live Authentication (RST) via SOAP

Tags: java, windows, authentication, soap, live

Does anybody has any pointer regarding this?

We are currently trying with Java SOAP API.
The URL used for windows live authentication is: https://login.live.com/RST2.srf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
  <s:Header>
    <wsa:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To s:mustUnderstand="1">HTTPS://login.live.com:443//RST2.srf</wsa:To>
    <wsa:MessageID>1265627255</wsa:MessageID>
    <ps:AuthInfo xmlns:ps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/PPCRL" Id="PPAuthInfo">
      <ps:HostingApp>{52B7DF4E-8D6F-49B5-BA7A-2E77B06DF104}</ps:HostingApp>
      <ps:BinaryVersion>5</ps:BinaryVersion>
      <ps:UIVersion>1</ps:UIVersion>
      <ps:Cookies/>
      <ps:RequestParams>AQAAAAIAAABsYwQAAAAxMDMz</ps:RequestParams>
    </ps:AuthInfo>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="user">
        <wsse:Username>harvinder_singh@persistent.co.in</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>jigsaw</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp Id="Timestamp">
        <wsu:Created>2010-02-08T11:07:36Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2010-02-08T11:12:36Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <wst:RequestSecurityToken Id="RST0">
      <wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType>
      <wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wsa:EndpointReference>
          <wsa:Address>http://Passport.NET/tb</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <wsp:PolicyReference URI="MBI_SSL"/>
    </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

### Request

```
curl -v -X POST \
  -A 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; IDCRL 4.100.313.1; IDCRL-cfg 4.0.5633.0; App msnmsgr.exe, 8.1.178.0, {7108E71A-9926-4FCB-BCC9-9A9D3F32E423})' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --data @soap-envelope.xml \
  https://login.live.com/RST.srf
```

#### SOAP Envelope (soap-envelope.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" xmlns:wssc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/sc" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/trust">
  <Header>
    <ps:AuthInfo xmlns:ps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/PPCRL" Id="PPAuthInfo">
      <ps:HostingApp>{7108E71A-9926-4FCB-BCC9-9A9D3F32E423}</ps:HostingApp>
      <ps:BinaryVersion>4</ps:BinaryVersion>
      <ps:UIVersion>1</ps:UIVersion>
      <ps:Cookies/>
      <ps:RequestParams>AQAAAAIAAABsYwQAAAAyMDUy</ps:RequestParams>
    </ps:AuthInfo>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:UsernameToken Id="user">
        <wsse:Username>user@hotmail.com</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <ps:RequestMultipleSecurityTokens xmlns:ps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/PPCRL" Id="RSTS">
      <wst:RequestSecurityToken Id="RST0">
        <wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/security/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType>
        <wsp:AppliesTo>
          <wsa:EndpointReference>
            <wsa:Address>http://Passport.NET/tb</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
      </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
      <wst:RequestSecurityToken Id="RST1">
        <wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/security/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType>
        <wsp:AppliesTo>
          <wsa:EndpointReference>
            <wsa:Address>messenger.msn.com</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wsse:PolicyReference URI="?MBI_KEY_OLD"/>
      </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
    </ps:RequestMultipleSecurityTokens>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

### Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Header>
    <psf:pp xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
      <psf:serverVersion>1</psf:serverVersion>
      <psf:PUID>00064000ACB2DA4B</psf:PUID>
      <psf:configVersion>10.000.17163.00</psf:configVersion>
      <psf:uiVersion>3.100.2179.0</psf:uiVersion>
      <psf:mobileConfigVersion>7.0.13347.0</psf:mobileConfigVersion>
      <psf:authstate>0x48803</psf:authstate>
      <psf:reqstatus>0x0</psf:reqstatus>
      <psf:serverInfo Path="Live1" RollingUpgradeState="ExclusiveNew" LocVersion="0" ServerTime="2012-02-28T18:02:53Z">BAYIDSLGN1M23 2012.01.05.13.58.58</psf:serverInfo>
      <psf:cookies/>
      <psf:browserCookies>
        <psf:browserCookie Name="MH" URL="http://www.msn.com">MSFT; path=/; domain=.msn.com; expires=Wed, 30-Dec-2037 16:00:00 GMT</psf:browserCookie>
        <psf:browserCookie Name="MHW" URL="http://www.msn.com">; path=/; domain=.msn.com; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT</psf:browserCookie>
        <psf:browserCookie Name="MH" URL="http://www.live.com">MSFT; path=/; domain=.live.com; expires=Wed, 30-Dec-2037 16:00:00 GMT</psf:browserCookie>
        <psf:browserCookie Name="MHW" URL="http://www.live.com">; path=/; domain=.live.com; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT</psf:browserCookie>
      </psf:browserCookies>
      <psf:credProperties>
        <psf:credProperty Name="MainBrandID">MSFT</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="BrandIDList"/>
        <psf:credProperty Name="IsWinLiveUser">true</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="CID">[cid]</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="AuthMembername">user@hotmail.com</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="Country">US</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="Language">1033</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="FirstName">User</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="LastName">Name</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="Flags">40100443</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="IP">[ip]</psf:credProperty>
        <psf:credProperty Name="AssociatedForStrongAuth">0</psf:credProperty>
      </psf:credProperties>
      <psf:extProperties>
        <psf:extProperty Name="ANON" Expiry="Sun, 16-Sep-2012 01:02:53 GMT" Domains="bing.com;atdmt.com" IgnoreRememberMe="false">A=E594CCB6E68C3EE6D7791CA6FFFFFFFF&amp;E=c58&amp;W=1</psf:extProperty>
        <psf:extProperty Name="NAP" Expiry="Fri, 08-Jun-2012 01:02:53 GMT" Domains="bing.com;atdmt.com" IgnoreRememberMe="false">V=1.9&amp;E=bfe&amp;C=m2GHblEqDDQP4-wYJOPUUAHW4oDsyX97spFHjQr-H1qHHQVZ4qfpgQ&amp;W=1</psf:extProperty>
        <psf:extProperty Name="LastUsedCredType">1</psf:extProperty>
        <psf:extProperty Name="WebCredType">1</psf:extProperty>
        <psf:extProperty Name="CID">[cid]</psf:extProperty>
      </psf:extProperties>
      <psf:response/>
    </psf:pp>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
    <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/trust" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy" xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
      <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
        <wst:TokenType>urn:passport:legacy</wst:TokenType>
        <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xml soap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing">
          <wsa:EndpointReference>
            <wsa:Address>http://Passport.NET/tb</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wst:LifeTime>
          <wsu:Created>2012-02-28T18:02:53Z</wsu:Created>
          <wsu:Expires>2012-02-29T18:02:53Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wst:LifeTime>
        <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
          <EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="BinaryDAToken0" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <ds:KeyName>http://Passport.NET/STS</ds:KeyName>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
              <CipherValue>[cipher]</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
          </EncryptedData>
        </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <wst:RequestedTokenReference>
          <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="urn:passport"/>
          <wsse:Reference URI="#BinaryDAToken0"/>
        </wst:RequestedTokenReference>
        <wst:RequestedProofToken>
          <wst:BinarySecret>[secret]</wst:BinarySecret>
        </wst:RequestedProofToken>
      </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
      <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
        <wst:TokenType>urn:passport:legacy</wst:TokenType>
        <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing">
          <wsa:EndpointReference>
            <wsa:Address>messenger.msn.com</wsa:Address>
          </wsa:EndpointReference>
        </wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wst:LifeTime>
          <wsu:Created>2012-02-28T18:02:53Z</wsu:Created>
          <wsu:Expires>2012-02-28T18:11:13Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wst:LifeTime>
        <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
          <wsse:BinarySecurityToken Id="PPToken1">t=[token]</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <wst:RequestedTokenReference>
          <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="urn:passport"/>
          <wsse:Reference URI="#PPToken1"/>
        </wst:RequestedTokenReference>
      </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I redacted sensitive bits with `[foo]`-style substitutions.

Comment: Hi brad. any chance you can post some reference to any links you had in order to create this process?

Answer (score 1):

Use consent

```
https://consent.live.com/Delegation.aspx?
ps = Passport service you want (Contacts.update|Contacts.index....)
ru = Return URL
pl = Policy url
app = your appid+timestamp+signature
```

If you link your users to this, Microsoft Live Service will authenticate your app then send a token as a base64 encrypted parameter to Return URL, you can parse that to get the Delegated Token for the user, their live id, the life-expectancy of the token, the permissions available and various other bits of information

Have a look here for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287637.aspx