# Windows live authentication without web browser

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to access O365 site with Windows Live authentication from windows application. With Web Browser control I am able to do it. The problem is this tool runs for more than 15 hrs and within this time frame FedAuth cookies expires and I need to again refresh the cookies without bringing up the Web Browser control. And the other reason why I cannot have Web Browser control is that this application also supports windows service mode.
We have automated the ADFS authentication through Http Requests but for Windows Live authentication there are some javascript involved to actually do the login.

I have tried the SOAP approach mentioned here [How to do Windows Live Authentication (RST) via SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229646/how-to-do-windows-live-authentication-rst-via-soap), it returns the Request Security Token but it is not in the same format which ACS (Azure Control Service) returns.

Please suggest any work around or technique I can use to achieve this goal.